# Batch - Kill program if running, start it if it's not

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

I'm trying to make a toggle batch script for a process so that if it's running it gets killed and if it's not it is started. This is what I have:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ProcessName.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "ProcessName.exe">NUL
set procopen = %ERRORLEVEL%
if "%procopen%"=="0" taskkill /im ProcessName.exe 
if NOT "%procopen%"=="0" start "" ProcessName.exe
```

But everytime I run it, after the first if statement I receive the error:

```
"1"=="0") was unexpected at this time.
```

I also feel like there's a more efficient way to write this, but I'm not exactly sure how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @rojo, there were no other lines in the script, that was it. But your suggestion worked! I modified the second part so it was `(start "" application.exe)` because I wanted the console to close, but other than that it worked perfectly! If you want to add an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Answer added.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More efficient would be to use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).

```
tasklist | find /i "application.exe" >NUL && (
    taskkill /im "application.exe" /f
) || (
    start "" application.exe
)
```

I think the reason your script is failing is because you've got spaces surrounding your equal sign in your `set procopen` line.  You're basically setting a variable named `procopen`<kbd>space</kbd>=<kbd>space</kbd>`numeral`, with the spaces included in both the variable name and the value.  In the `set` command, spaces are treated as literal space characters, rather than as token delimiters.  Now if you had done `set /a`, it probably would've worked (as `set /a` is more tolerant of spacing).  Or if you had left the spaces out and `set "procopen=%ERRORLEVEL%"`, that probably would've worked too.  Here's an example cmd console session to demonstrate:

> `C:\Users\me>set procopen = 0`
>
> `C:\Users\me>set "res=%procopen%"`
>
> `C:\Users\me>set res`
>   `res=%procopen%`
>
> `C:\Users\me>set "res=%procopen %"`
>
> `C:\Users\me>set res`
>   `res= 0`

Comment: Thanks! Your solution fixed it for me